# Add animation to jQuery function insertAfter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, insertafter

How can I add animation on this code ?

```
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 93){  
    $('#primary_nav').addClass("navighez");
    $('#primary_nav').insertAfter('#logo').animate({margin-right:"300px"});
  } 
  else{
    //back to default styles
    $('#primary_nav').removeClass("navighez");
  }
```

Comment: Well, maybe it would work if you remove the syntax error... `'margin-right'` or `marginRight`

Comment: Yes, not it's working. Sorry, but i'm newbie in javascript! :)